# Calculating an improper integral.

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

There is an improper integral which has to be calculated and I have no idea about it. The problem is in the argument of cosine being just $x$ and not $ax$. If it were $ax$, the problem would have been trivial. Here it is: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{a x \cos(x)-\sin(ax)}{x^2} \, dx, \qquad a>0$$
No complex analysis is allowed to use, only calculus knowledge, for example, differentiating integrals depending on a parameter.

Comment: Is this for a competition?

Comment: No, this is a problem from a pre-exam work at my university, which I wrote a couple of weeks ago, and I didn't calculate this/

Comment: It's easy to show that it is convergent.

Comment: So yes, this integral converges, but I do not see symmetric bounds and I do not see an odd function there.

Answer (score 5):

If $\text{Ci}(x)$ is an antiderivative of $\cos(x)/x$, an antiderivative of your integrand is $$ F(x) = \frac{\sin(ax)}{x} - a\; \text{Ci}(ax) + a\; \text{Ci}(x)$$
Now $\text{Ci}(t) \sim \text{constant} + \ln(t)$ as $t \to 0+$, while
$\text{Ci}(t) \to \text{constant}$ as $t \to +\infty$.
So the answer is $a \ln(a) - a$.

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for comments but this is an interesting integral.*
$$I=\int\frac{a x \cos(x)-\sin(ax)}{x^2} \, dx=a\int\frac{ \cos(x)}x \, dx-\int \frac{\sin(ax)} {x^2}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{ \cos(x)}x \, dx=\text{Ci}(x)$$
$$\int \frac{\sin(ax)} {x^2}\,dx=a\int \frac{\sin(y)} {y^2}\,dy$$
One integration by parts gives
$$\int \frac{\sin(y)} {y^2}\,dy=\text{Ci}(y)-\frac{\sin (y)}{y}$$ Back to $x$
$$I=a \,\text{Ci}(x)-a \,\text{Ci}(a x)+\frac{\sin (a x)}{x}$$
Now, considering
$$J(t)=\int_t^\infty\frac{a x \cos(x)-\sin(ax)}{x^2} \, dx$$
$$\lim_{t\to \infty } \, J(t)=0$$

$$J(t)=a(1-\log (a))+\frac a2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\,\frac{a^{2n}-(2n+1) } {n\,(2n+1)!} t^{2n}$$